# No association found for name Cocoon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I'm using the cocoon gem.
I have the following error association

No association found for name `tasks'. Has it been defined yet?

in model dimension

```
class Dimension < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :task
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true 
end
```

Model Task

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :dimension
end
```

I've tried everything, reviewing other projects but can not find solution

here's the link of the project on github
https://github.com/renatoVB/testcocoon

Answer (score 0):

You defined association in `Dimension` as singular `task`. It should be defined as plural:

```
class Dimension < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, :reject_if => :all_blank,   :allow_destroy => true 
end
```